# Move Laravel to different server

Tags: laravel

I am having a trouble moving my Laravel project between servers.
I have it on WAMP server with no problems. Then I have this shared XAMPP server. I connect to it remotely with no problems, installed composer and Laravel with no problems. I already got the Welcome view to show.
My next step was to delete all files in the new Laravel project and copy all the files from my previous project into the new project folder. Then I created a phpMyadmin user, with the same username, the same password, the same database name. But, when I try to enter the public root, I'm getting an

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'xxxxxx'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

error.

I can connect only to a certain views, but just blank views, with just the html code.

I also cannot use the

> php artisan migrate

command, it gives a

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'The stream or file "C:\xampp_1_8_2\htdocs\laravel\storage/logs/laravel-2015-03-23.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied' in C:\xampp_1_8_2\htdocs\laravel\vendor\monolog\monolog\src\Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler.php:84
>   Stack trace:#0 C:\xampp_1_8_2\htdocs\laravel\vendor\monolog\monolog\src\Monolog\Handler\Rota
>   tingFileHandler.php(88): Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler->write(Array)#1 C:\xampp_1_8_2\htdocs\laravel\vendor\monolog\monolog\src\Monolog\HandlerAbstractProcessingHandler.php(37): Monolog\HandlerRotatingFileHandler->write(Array).......

Is there something I forgot to do?

**SOLVED**!!!
adding `'port' => 'xxxx',` to conf/database.php, where xxxx is the server port, did the trick for both of the problems!

Comment: first of all change the permission of `storage/` then change your configs to match the database server's. Easy as pie.

Comment: Probably it is easy, yes, but where can I find those configs?
And `storage/` permissions changing is just removing the Read-only option in folder properties, right?

Comment: chmod 755 -R laravel and  chmod -R o+w storage,
and recheck your database credentials  this error code is belongs to wrong credentials

Comment: I'm on xampp Windows server. I believe those commands wont work here?

Comment: No they arent but windows got permissions as well and if your user doesnt have write permissions then you wouldnt be able to write this file but instead of fixing this issue first check your db password as you wouldnt be able to migrate any how without the right credentials

Comment: Okay, ill ask to grand me all permissions on that folder.
I double checked, re-made mysql user, it has the same password, username, DB name as i have written in my .env file and the connection to .env file also should be correct, because it worked on my previous server.

Comment: just found out, that I have all the permissions on that folder, but not the subfolders and files. If I change that, will it be okay?

Comment: @mejidarif could you please walk me through changing my configs to match the database server's?